# How to use SVGs and image fallbacks with ReactJs?

Tags: svg, reactjs, fallback

I am currently using ReactJs for one of my project. Since we all thing in terms of components when it comes to ReactJs, how do we approach having SVGs/fallbacks in React application?

Do we build component for each SVG? or is there a different way you React users build them? I just want to approaching it with the best practise!

I would be really happy if someone helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [material-ui library's approach to SVG support](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/svg-icon). They have [a SvgIcon component](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/svg-icon.jsx) which you should be able to reuse. Their approach is having the common implementation separated out in the SvgIcon component and then having [individual component wrappers for each unique SVG icon](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/src/svg-icons).

Comment: Thanks for the links. So it means that the best practise is to wrap svgs into its own component?

Comment: The issue with linked SVG files is that they use case-sensitive tags, which conflict with React, so you must include the path inside the JSX code itself. For the sake of modularity, it is best to keep them separate in their own files.